# Are sheaf restrictions epimorphisms in an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $a\in A$. The restriction on the Zariski open $D(a)$ is the localization morphism $A\to A_a$, which is a ring epimorphism. Is it also true for any Zariski open $U$ not in the $D$ basis?

Geometrically it would mean restrictions produce smaller shapes, which makes sense. I am struggling with characterizing prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}(U)$ so far. They should be in bijection with $U$.

Comment: Not every open subscheme of an affine scheme is affine, so in fact $O (U)$ may have more (or less) prime ideals than you expect.

Comment: @ZhenLin does this mean the answer is no, the restriction to $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is not necessarily a ring epimorphism?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. For example, it is well known that $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \}$ is not affine. But the restriction is an isomorphism.